# Laravel 5 migration gone wrong

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I created a new migration with `php artisan make:migration --table=my_table` and proceed to create a new column to an existing table. Said column is supposed to be a `unique index`, but I forgot to make it nullable, for that reason, `php artisan migrate` failed, as multiple rows would have a duplicate entry (which would be an empty string `''`)

Up to this point, the logical way to go is to add `nullable` to the column and re-run migrations. But since the new column already exist on the table (the migration failed when adding the unique key, but the column creation was successful) I have to drop it first.

My first thought was to run `php artisan migrate:rollback` but it executed a previous migration, not the one I just created.

Up to this point, what is the right way to do this? should I log into database cli and write query manually  or laravel provide a way to handle this via `php artisan`?

Comment: is the application on the development environment or on the production environment ?

Comment: It is on development, but I'd don't want to migrate:refresh because at some point I'm gonna have to migrate to production, and I cannot do that on prod

Answer (score 0):

I do think you can modify the original migration for your table and add the `nullable`, but you need to do this on the old migration. As you noticed, a new migration will just apply a patch to an existing table.

After modifying the migration you can rollback and forward again. Of course you need to be careful with your data (in case you need them check [Database Seeding](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/migrations#database-seeding).

You can also use `php artisan migrate:refresh` this will delete all tables and data (so be really careful), but it should recreate your table with the new structure.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
 php artisan migrate:rollback --table=table_name_here
```

Comment: Migrations are done in batches, stored in the migrations table. You cannot roll back an individual table like this. See mucio's answer.